# Team Foundation Server Removes Icon From VB6 Applications

Tags: vb6, tfs

I am using TFS with a lot of VB6 applications and have noticed that since using TFS after checking out the vbp file doing some changes and checking in, the line in the vbp file specifying the IconForm is missing. Nothing else seems to be missing but it is very annoying having to go into each project and re-specify the icon to use.

I have managed to replicate this - Load up project and in the IDE check out my VBP file, then check out the form that the project is using for the icon, check the properties of the project and the Icon is now set to nothing.

Has anyone encountered this? And is there a fix?

Answer (score 0):

Strange. Are you sure it isn't the VB6 IDE itself? Maybe the existing IconForm line was incorrect and it's silently removing the line when it resaves the VBP? It should look like this and the form must actually be in the project under the same name.

```
IconForm="frmMain"
```

VB6 documentation is terse on the [VBP](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa716294%28v=VS.60%29.aspx) file format but I think `IconForm` is the symbolic name rather than the filename.